# Initializing a variable with a function reference (PHP)

Tags: php, php5

I'm working on an old PHP website, and NetBeans is complaining about an uninitialized variable. I'm seeing some code like this:

```
$app->soapAPIVersion($apiVersion);
$_SESSION['apiVersion'] = $apiVersion;
```

The function looks something like this:

```
function soapAPIVersion(&$apiVersion)
{
    $apiVersion = '';
    $result = false;
    $soapResult = $client->call('getAPIVersion', array('sessionKey' => $sessionKey), $url);

    if (is_string($soapResult))
    {
        $apiVersion = $soapResult;
        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;    
}
```

I believe it's using this line to initialize the `$apiVersion` variable:

```
$app->soapAPIVersion($apiVersion);
```

For better coding practice, should that really be this:

```
$apiVersion = '';
$app->soapAPIVersion($apiVersion);
```

Or is it a valid trick?

Comment: While I agree with the advice to refactor and avoid the reference, *sometimes* you have no choice (e.g. the built-in function `preg_match`). Yes, this is a [bug in NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242520), and there's no reason to initialize `$apiVersion` before calling the function. You will only get a warning if you *read* its value before initializing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With all do respect, this code really did hurt. Netbeans is complaining, because the function `soapAPIVersion` expects a *reference* to a variable. You're passing an undeclared, and uninitialized variable to the function. Sort of like a void pointer/null-pointer thing.
It's not really a big deal, but I cannot, for the life of me, get *why* this function uses a reference as an argument. I think it better to change it to:

```
function soapAPIVersion()
{
    $soapResult = $client->call('getAPIVersion', array('sessionKey' => $sessionKey), $url);
    if (is_string($soapResult))
    {
        return $soapResult;
    }
    //implicitly return null, or throw exception
}
```

And call it like so:

```
$apiVersion = $app->soapAPIVersion();
if ($apiVersion === null)
{
    throw new RuntimeException('unable to get the API version');
}
$_SESSION['apiVersion'] = $apiVersion;
```

Bottom line: only pass by reference if you need your function to do 2 things *at the same time*, and you can't split those two things over 2 functions. situations are *Very* rare. Since PHP5, I've only had to use a reference argument 5~10 times, I think, so avoid, if at all possible

Comment: Excellent, fully agree, thankyou! Unfortunately what you saw was just the very tip of the iceberg. This code base has more of the same and even worse examples.

Comment: @user2640336: In that case, even though I'm not religious, I'll pray for your sanity :)

Answer (score 5):

1. *Clean Code, Chapter 3. Functions* has some guidance:

   > **Have No Side Effects**
   >
   > Side effects are lies. Your function promises to do one thing, but it also does other hidden
   >   things.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > Anything that forces you to check the function signature is equivalent to a double-take. It’s
   >   a cognitive break and should be avoided.

   The side effect here is that the function changes the argument. A more readable approach would be returning the API version (instead of true/false) or throwing an exception in case of errors.
2. ```
   $app->soapAPIVersion($apiVersion);
   $_SESSION['apiVersion'] = $apiVersion;
   ```

   Note that the code should check the return value of `soapAPIVersion` and handle `false` somehow.
3. The `soapAPIVersion` name is unclear. What does it do with the API version? From *Clean Code, Chapter 2: Meaningful Names*:

   > **Method Names**
   >
   > Methods should have verb or verb phrase names like postPayment, deletePage, or save.
   >   Accessors, mutators, and predicates should be named for their value and prefixed with get,
   >   set, and is according to the javabean standard.

   I'd rename it to `getApiVersion` or `fetchApiVersion`.

   Note the camelCase too which is usually easier to read. From *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*:

   > While uppercase may be more common, 
   >   a strong argument can made in favor of capitalizing only the first 
   >   letter: even if multiple acronyms occur back-to-back, you can still 
   >   tell where one word starts and the next word ends. 
   >   Which class name would you rather see, HTTPURL or HttpUrl?